# Where can I learn to make a custom Drupal Template

Tags: templates, drupal, content-management-system, themes

I have a serious question. Where can I learn to make a custom Drupal template. For example, I have a mock up landing page, containing a background image covering the entire screen, then I have a three column grid below it. Off course the pre built Drupal template does not have a matching template to my mock up. How else can I make a custom Drupal template?

Alternatives: I read the Drupal 7 themes, and it did not show a step by step on creating themes, just a vague brief explanation on editing sub pages, and making sub pages. I could not find any college courses that teaches this either. If anyone can provide resources, please, I would seriously appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of tutorials online. Just pick some:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming

http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-create-drupal-7-theme-scratch

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-new-drupal-theme/

http://www.tenten71.com/drupal-theme-from-scratch/